# Basic Dagger 2 activity injection

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am following the dagger 2 tutorial [here](https://github.com/ecgreb/dagger-2-testing-demo):

Everything works fine, but I want to create a module that takes an activity (or later a fragment maybe) in the constructor as it needs it. So it will look like:

```
@Module
public class AndroidModule {
    private final AppCompatActivity activity;

    public AndroidModule(AppCompatActivity act) {
        this.activity = act;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton StringFactory provideStringFactory() {
        return new StringFactory(activity);
    }
}
```

But from what I understand, this means that I can no longer create my component from the application class, and I have to move the following code into the activity (and change component name etc):

```
@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    component = DaggerMyApplication_ApplicationComponent.builder()
            .androidModule(new AndroidModule(this))
            .commonModule(new CommonModule())
            .build();
}
```

So my question is, is there another way to do that? Because for testing I don't see how I can provide a different component to that activity, as the creation is inside it. In that case I don't see why this is any better than just directly constructing the object there. I am sure I am missing something however.

I tried doing

```
@Module
public class AndroidModule {

    @Provides StringFactory provideStringFactory(Activity activity) {
        return new StringFactory(activity);
    }
}
```

But that provided errors such as

```
Error:(12, 14) error: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
com.ecgreb.dagger2testingdemo.MainActivity.stringFactory
[injected field of type: com.ecgreb.dagger2testingdemo.StringFactory stringFactory]
com.ecgreb.dagger2testingdemo.AndroidModule.provideStringFactory(android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity activity)
[parameter: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity activity]
```

Comment: You *will* have to use more than one component. And you probably should have a look at some more tutorials, component dependencies and subcomponents. And then Scopes in more detail.

Comment: Check out, for example, this project: https://github.com/patloew/countries